# Grafana - How to fix/hide UI Notifications with messages (DashboardQueryRunner Failed, Load Failed, etc.)

Tags: kubernetes, iframe, prometheus, grafana

I am using Grafana Version - 10.0.2 (the problem existed in previous versions as well) deployed on Kubernetes running on Ubuntu machine.

I am using Grafana to monitor Kubernetes resources using data from prometheus.

The dashboards are working fine, and as intended, however, randomly while switching through dashboards or while reloading a dashboard, a red box error pops up with messages such as (DashboardQueryRunner Failed, Load Failed, etc.)

I would like to know what these errors are and how to fix them, or if not, how can I disable these red alerts/notifications (as the dashboards are showing up correctly anyway).

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag0Fz.png)

I have tried various different solutions which seemed somewhat similar to the problem I was facing like the ones listed here.

https://grafana.docs.cern.ch/4._Troubleshooting/2-proxy-error-context-canceled/ https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/7649